# LocalDateTime of type format problem in thymeleaf

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, web, servlets, thymeleaf

I'm studying JavaWeb now,but not enough experience to solve the problem.

I use MySql 8.0+, "mysql-connector-java" version by maven impot is 8.0.12,JDBC connect MySql Driver use "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";DataBase table date time field type is " datetime",the field can be read successful by invoked set in JavaBean attribute "orderDate",then let attribute "orderDate" through  'HttpSession session' to set in session.

When JavaBean attribute type is " java.sql.Timestamp ", from session read variable values,the thymeleaf format work is fine;
There is the source code:

```html
<td th:text="${#dates.format(orderBean.getOrderDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"></td>
```

But when JavaBean attribute type is " java.time.LocalDateTime ",the "orderBean.java" part source code:

```java
public class OrderBean {
   ....
    private LocalDateTime orderDate;
   .....

    public LocalDateTime getOrderDate() {
       return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(LocalDateTime orderDate) {
      this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }
}
```

There is a method to set orderBean to HttpSeesion part source code:

```java
public String checkout(HttpSession session){
        ........
        OrderBean orderBean = new OrderBean();
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        orderBean.setOrderDate(localDateTime);
        session.setAttribute("orderBean",orderBean);
        ........
        return "cart/cart";
}
```

There is the cart.html source code:

```html
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(orderBean.getOrderDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"></td>
```

from session read variable values,the thymeleaf format not in effect,throw the erro:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "#temporals.format(orderBean.getOrderDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')" (template: "order/order" - line 48, col 19)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:191)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
```

I try to solve it ,but i search in google,they write code like the same that.But the different is that they  use SpringMVC, through "model.setAttribute()" method ,

```java
model.addAttribute("localDate", LocalDate.now());
```

then through thymeleaf expression:

```html
<p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDateTime, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></p>
```

In addition,i also import dependency in maven  artifactId "thymeleaf-extras-java8time ";
I just use javax-Servlet-api ,without spring,springMVC stc...,I'm devastated that I don't know how to solve it.

I hope someone can help me....

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the statement itself `${#temporals.format(orderBean.orderDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}` should be fine asuming you've defined orderBean in your model. To say more going to atleast need the full stacktrace as usualy a thymeleaf error says which component of the statement is wrong at a lower level

Comment: Thank for you answer,but I am not good at English,i can't understand  your last long sentence entirely.You mean that this  thymeleaf error show  it is a lower level wrong ?And from HttpSession get LocalDateTime variable to format grammar like what i do  is right?